# how to add & remove layout element between portarit mode and landscape mode?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I have a simple layout, which shows a text and a image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
>    
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
    >

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TEST"
            android:textColor="#0099cc"
        />

        <ImageView   
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tint="#55ff0000"
            android:src="@drawable/my_image"/>
    </LinearLayout>    


</LinearLayout>
```

I would like the image to be shown only when the device is in **Portrait** mode.

What I mean is if the device is in **landscape** mode, I would like to **not only** just *hide* the image, **but remove the image completely** from the layout. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify two layouts: one fort portrait mode, placed in layout-port folder, and one for landscape mode, placed in layout-land folder. Hope this helps.

Comment: @ Egor , I even forgot this feature. Thank you for your remind.

Answer (score 4):

Android provides for this by allowing you to have multiple layout files in separate layout folders which are used in different environments.

You should move this xml file to a new `res/layout-port` folder in your directory structure, and create a copy in `res/layout-land` which lacks your `ImageView`. Android will select the appropriate XML file depending on which orientation the device is in.

There's more information [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).